# Hide request parameters in apex url

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex, http-request-parameters

Is there any way to hide request parameters in apex URL?

For an example, I have below URL with request parameter `TYPE`.

https://mydomain.me/apex/f?p=115:28:18817528642526:TYPE:NO::P28_ROOM_ID:103

I don't need to reveal this request parameter to end user. How can I hide this from end user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're worried about URL tampering (e.g. the user figuring out the URL syntax and hacking it), you should set **Page Access Protection** to **Arguments Must Have Checksum**. This will mean the user cannot change any of the URL parameters (including the Request) without getting an error.

If you're worried about users knowing the *name* of the request, e.g. if it suggests something to them, why not obfuscate it? Instead of `TYPE`, send `X` or `X3895DGFH` or whatever.